# Leiningen Emacs and Clojure

Tags: emacs, clojure

I have a project setup at the moment that works like a charm when I use `lein run`. 
The minimal case that causes the problem is the following. I have two files, shown below. The `core.clj` file is supposed to throw an error and then stop. The error is simply an error that extends the standard `Error` of Java. However, when I open up this file in emacs and open up cider I can't get it to compile properly.

## core.clj

```
(ns meta-clojure.core
  (:import (org.jsoup Jsoup)
           (java.lang String)
           (meta_clojure.stm RetryEx)))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println "Throwing exception now..")
  (throw (RetryEx. "this is broken"))
  (println "End of main")
  nil)
```

## RetryEx.clj

```
(ns meta-clojure.stm.RetryEx
  (:gen-class :extends java.lang.Error))
```

Now, as I said, when I run the `lein run` command it executes just fine. However, in emacs I get the following stack trace:

```
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: meta_clojure.stm.RetryEx, compiling:(/home/christophe/bitbucket/meta-clojure/src/meta_clojure/core.clj:1:1)
                                Compiler.java:7142 clojure.lang.Compiler.load
                                  NO_SOURCE_FILE:1 user/eval931
                                Compiler.java:6703 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval
                                Compiler.java:6666 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval
                                     core.clj:2927 clojure.core/eval
                                      main.clj:239 clojure.main/repl[fn]
                                      main.clj:239 clojure.main/repl[fn]
                                      main.clj:257 clojure.main/repl[fn]
                                      main.clj:257 clojure.main/repl
                                  RestFn.java:1523 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
                         interruptible_eval.clj:67 clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate[fn]
                                      AFn.java:152 clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper
                                      AFn.java:144 clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo
                                      core.clj:624 clojure.core/apply
                                     core.clj:1862 clojure.core/with-bindings*
                                   RestFn.java:425 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
                         interruptible_eval.clj:51 clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
                        interruptible_eval.clj:183 clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/interruptible-eval[fn]
                        interruptible_eval.clj:152 clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/run-next[fn]
                                       AFn.java:22 clojure.lang.AFn.run
                      ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
                       ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
                                   Thread.java:745 java.lang.Thread.run
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: meta_clojure.stm.RetryEx
                           URLClassLoader.java:366 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run
                           URLClassLoader.java:355 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run
                                  (Unknown Source) java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged
                           URLClassLoader.java:354 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass
                        DynamicClassLoader.java:61 clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader.findClass
                              ClassLoader.java:425 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
                              ClassLoader.java:358 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass
                                  (Unknown Source) java.lang.Class.forName0
                                    Class.java:191 java.lang.Class.forName
                                        core.clj:1 meta-clojure.core/eval935[fn]
                                        core.clj:1 meta-clojure.core/eval935
                                Compiler.java:6703 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval
                                Compiler.java:6692 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval
                                Compiler.java:7130 clojure.lang.Compiler.load
```

Could anyone help me out please? I think I need to tell Cider/Emacs to compile ahead of time or something. Perhaps leiningen compiles to different directories than emacs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you need to compile the meta-clojure.stm.RetryEx namespace to produce the class files before you can include it. This is sometimes useful if you are writing a class for consumption by a Java library and core.clj is only a test harness for developing, though it's not the easy or typical way to go about it. It is a bit more common to **use require instead of include to refer to a clojure namespace** from with a Clojure project.

You can check what is actually been compiled by looking in the `target/classes` directory of the project. before compiling I see:

```
arthur@a:~/meta-clojure$ ls target/classes/
META-INF
```

Then after compiling it from the repl:

```
user> (compile 'meta-clojure.stm.RetryEx)
meta-clojure.stm.RetryEx
user> 
meta-clojure.core> (-main )
Throwing exception now..
RetryEx this is broken  meta-clojure.core/-main (core.clj:6)
meta-clojure.core>
```

And checking the same directory:

```
arthur@a:~/meta-clojure$ ls -R  target/classes/
target/classes/:
meta_clojure  META-INF

target/classes/meta_clojure:
stm

target/classes/meta_clojure/stm:
RetryEx.class  RetryEx$fn__3333.class  RetryEx$fn__3351.class  RetryEx__init.class  RetryEx$loading__4958__auto__.class

target/classes/META-INF:
maven

target/classes/META-INF/maven:
meta-clojure

target/classes/META-INF/maven/meta-clojure:
meta-clojure

target/classes/META-INF/maven/meta-clojure/meta-clojure:
pom.properties
```

Leiningen is happy to do the AOT compiling for you, if you specify which namespaces require it:

project.clj:

```
(defproject meta-clojure "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]]
  :aot [meta-clojure.stm.RetryEx])
```

and then run `lein compile`:

```
arthur@a:~/meta-clojure$ lein compile
Compiling meta-clojure.stm.RetryEx
arthur@a:~/meta-clojure$ ls target/classes/
meta_clojure/ META-INF/     
arthur@a:~/meta-clojure$ ls target/classes/meta_clojure/stm/
```

PS: you also don't need to include `java.lang.String` it's included by default.